# Group Latitude and Longitude by distance with Javascript

Tags: javascript, markerclusterer

I have 77 Latitude and Longitude points in a Javascript Array, I need to order this array in a group by proximity clustering then in group of 8, how can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/mn8v7d3L/2/

```
var markers = [
  [-23.5505199,-46.63330939999997],
  [-23.70076253,-46.45489123],
  ...
];

function initializeMaps() {
var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
var marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    bounds.extend(pos);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
       icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2%7C"+hue
    });
    j++;
    if(j==8){
        j=0;
      hue = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)) + '00'+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)) ;
    }
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

initializeMaps();
```